# celebrate a victory on Facebook with open Graph Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i wanted to share a vicotry from my android app on facebook using open Graph , i tried to follow sharing using ShareOpenGraphObject [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#share_dialog) , and this is my source code

```
hareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                .putString("og:type", "game.achievement")
                .putString("og:title", "Playing")
                .putString("og:description", "I did " + manager.getScore() + " points")
                .putString("og:url", "https://www.facebook.com/")
                .putInt("game:points", 100)
                .build();
        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType("games.achieves")
                .putObject("game:achievement", object)
                .build();
        ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName("game:achievement")
                .setAction(action)
                .build();

        ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden here?

Comment: not working , just a share window appear and then disappear , so how we can do that !!

Comment: You need to provide a proper Open Graph object; you can not just use `https://www.facebook.com/` and hope it was the right type.

Comment: "com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 1 [message]: An unknown error has occurred. [extra]" thrown when I used this code. Any advices?